# Stop scrolling when there is no content left/

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, parallax

Scrolling with `CoordinatorLayout` is a great feature, however leaving a huge gap is an UX issue.
I have one activity which shows a user profile (which might be short or very long), and I want stop scrolling when there is no more information left (even if the picture hasn't disappeared).

For a better understanding here you have a picture sample of what I want.

[image: Picture sample]

Here you have the layout sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/a"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birthday"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh elit, ut iaculis dolor malesuada sit amet. Vestibulum sed erat id orci consectetur tempus. Praesent semper, elit vel ullamcorper fringilla, nisi elit vulputate sapien, a efficitur dolor tortor eu nulla. Sed ac tellus quis risus rutrum euismod. Aliquam ex ligula, pharetra et odio non, lobortis maximus libero. Sed ut dui ante. Quisque ac libero diam. Vivamus mattis vitae leo vel placerat. Quisque risus nulla, eleifend in sem a, placerat laoreet lorem. Donec fringilla egestas pharetra. Quisque non ante orci. Aliquam tincidunt aliquet ornare. Sed sed maximus orci. Maecenas vel feugiat quam.\nDonec ornare metus ut consequat dictum. Duis quis fringilla urna. Donec urna nibh, auctor id scelerisque varius, porttitor vitae felis. Proin ex arcu, pharetra ac nunc sit amet, laoreet ullamcorper lectus. Ut ac nibh lacus. Fusce augue est, finibus ut leo eget, mollis ultricies leo. Etiam eget dignissim enim. Aenean at eros molestie, viverra ligula vel, condimentum turpis. Fusce hendrerit sed eros id pulvinar. Morbi fermentum tempor mauris. Duis scelerisque sem a odio pulvinar, eu lacinia eros ullamcorper. Vivamus in sodales eros."
            />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: is the scrolling never stops?

Comment: @A.s.ALI It stops when the image fully disappears. However it leaves a huge gap in the bottom.

Comment: try changing this line app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

Comment: @A.s.ALI If I remove this attribute, the parallax effect goes away. I mean, I can only scroll the bottom part of the activity, but not the picture. I just want to keep the same effect, but with an early stop.

Comment: I said try changing the combinations not asked you to remove it. :) 
here you can see the parallax  affect combination  with different combinations for example app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"

Comment: @A.s.ALI I tried with `snap` and `snapMargin`, none of them worked. Which combination do you suggest?

Comment: currently I am working on iOS project, can you give me something to workwith, I am androdi project so that I can go through code directly

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't replicate your issue. As far as i can see you TextView with huge data is in nestedscrollview. This nothing had to do with bottom margin. scrolling stops just when the content finishes. I tried this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birthday" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh elit, ut iaculis dolor malesuada sit amet. Vestibulum sed erat id orci consectetur tempus. Praesent semper, elit vel ullamcorper fringilla, nisi elit vulputate sapien, a efficitur dolor tortor eu nulla. Sed ac tellus quis risus rutrum euismod. Aliquam ex ligula, pharetra et odio non, lobortis maximus libero. Sed ut dui ante. Quisque ac libero diam. Vivamus mattis vitae leo vel placerat. Quisque risus nulla, eleifend in sem a, placerat laoreet lorem. Donec fringilla egestas pharetra. Quisque non ante orci. Aliquam tincidunt aliquet ornare. Sed sed maximus orci. Maecenas vel feugiat quam.\nDonec ornare metus ut consequat dictum. Duis quis fringilla urna. Donec urna nibh, auctor id scelerisque varius, porttitor vitae felis. Proin ex arcu, pharetra ac nunc sit amet, laoreet ullamcorper lectus. Ut ac nibh lacus. Fusce augue est, finibus ut leo eget, mollis ultricies leo. Etiam eget dignissim enim. Aenean at eros molestie, viverra ligula vel, condimentum turpis. Fusce hendrerit sed eros id pulvinar. Morbi fermentum tempor mauris. Duis scelerisque sem a odio pulvinar, eu lacinia eros ullamcorper. Vivamus in sodales eros." />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh elit, ut iaculis dolor malesuada sit amet. Vestibulum sed erat id orci consectetur tempus. Praesent semper, elit vel ullamcorper fringilla, nisi elit vulputate sapien, a efficitur dolor tortor eu nulla. Sed ac tellus quis risus rutrum euismod. Aliquam ex ligula, pharetra et odio non, lobortis maximus libero. Sed ut dui ante. Quisque ac libero diam. Vivamus mattis vitae leo vel placerat. Quisque risus nulla, eleifend in sem a, placerat laoreet lorem. Donec fringilla egestas pharetra. Quisque non ante orci. Aliquam tincidunt aliquet ornare. Sed sed maximus orci. Maecenas vel feugiat quam.\nDonec ornare metus ut consequat dictum. Duis quis fringilla urna. Donec urna nibh, auctor id scele" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```